# Why my model and view object not displaying in JSP page .?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Hi I am using spring mvc .Sample of code below here.

```
  @Controller  
  public class WelcomeController {  

      @RequestMapping("/welcome")  
      public ModelAndView welcome() {  
          String message = "welcome to my tutorial";  
          return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);  
      }  
  }
```

But here this message is not able to fetch by jsp page it is;

```
    welcome.jsp 
   message:${message}
```

Only i am getting message: 
Nothing is displaying for error messgge.

```
Here Web.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app version="2.5"   
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">  
<servlet>  
<servlet-name>Dispatcherspring</servlet-name>  
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class><load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>Dispatcherspring</servlet-name>  
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app> 
 Here my Spring file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  
<context:component-scan  base-package="package-name" />  
<bean  
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
   </bean>  
   </beans>
```

Both xml and web.xml file i had post

Comment: Are you sure your request is being handled by Spring. Is it not going to the jsp directly. Post your web.xml and Spring configuration file

Comment: yes i am sure.If i am using JSP implicit Object Then i can do directly. But i want to go for Spring MVC

Comment: Post the web.xml and configuration file so we can assist

Answer (score 0):

Simply because you do not have `@Requestmapping` for the controller. 
Hence Spring is unable to reach to your controller and call welcome service.

```
@controller
@RequestMapping
Class WelcomeController{
    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getStudent(){
   }
}
```

Comment: Please read the documentation of GetMapping . Please understand the question then only answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    My controller is
    @Controller
    public class HouseController {

        @Autowired
        private HouseService houseService;

        @GetMapping(value = "/house")
        public ModelAndView get() {
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
            List<HouseDto> listHouse = houseService.listHouse();
            modelAndView.addObject("listHouse", listHouse);
            modelAndView.setViewName("house/listHouse");
            return modelAndView;
        }
    }

    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>

    ###JSP
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
                <c:forEach var="house" items="${listHouse}" varStatus="">
                            <tr>
                                <td>${house.name}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
         </div>
    <body>

 #<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    its work for me
```